# JQuery Sending value using GET not working

Tags: jquery, get

Sending the value of the select option is not working but I am able to get the value and print it, so it's definitely the `$.get`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
//hover method to drop down nav menu
.
.
.
.

$('select').change( function() {
    var val = $('#sortOpt').val();
    $.get(
        "http://localhost/e-com/index.php/products/categories?cat=cameras&",
        {
            sort: val
        },
        function(data){}
    )
});
});
```

Comment: What does arrive at the server? See access log or better look into the network tab of your JavaScript debugger to see what the get method sends.

Comment: It was sending nothing, but it's working now. I got this code from this site and I didn't know what `function(data){}` was, so removing it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the following :

```
   var val = $('#sortOpt').val();
//^remove the '$'
```

You've also got an extra `}` at the end of your `$.get()` call.

Once fixed, you should have:

```
$('select').change( function() {
    var val = $('#sortOpt').val();
    $.get(
        "http://localhost/e-com/index.php/products/categories?cat=cameras&",
        {
            sort: val
        },
        function(data){}
    );
});
```

Comment: the `$` sign is a typo when I deleted a line before that and the extra `{` is for `$(document).ready(function () { `

Comment: Ok, what is the #sortOpt element? Are you getting the "cat" value?

Comment: `#sortOpt` is a select option, yes I am able to get the cat value.

Comment: Do you mean to get the current selection? You can use $(this).val() to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should send data as url parameters:

```
$.get(
    "http://localhost/e-com/index.php/products/categories?cat=cameras&sort=" + val,
    function(data){}
});
```

Comment: That's effectively what he's doing at the moment. See the documentation for the second parameter to `get()`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get